# How to handle multiple requests when writing socks5 proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, web

Recently, I try to write socks5 server in python. you can see it [here](https://github.com/baiyang/lab/blob/master/socks5/socks5.py).

I begin to think a question. How I handle multiple requests from browser?
In this version, I use multiple threads to handle it. If I don't want to use multiple thread, How can I  design the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [`select`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#module-select) module. In particular look at the [`select()`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#select.select)
 function.

`select()` is pretty low-level. Another alternative is the standard Python [`asyncore`](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html#module-asyncore) module. Check out the example echo server to see how easy it is to use.

Comment: yeah, I did use select function. but I think asyncore module can reduce my codes. Thanks a lot.